# Strapi won't upload in prod

Tags: strapi, cloudinary

I installed in my folder the

```
yarn add strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary graphql
```

Registered at cloudinary and followed the steps

[Configuring Cloudinary with Strapi 3.1.4](https://cptcrunchy.medium.com/configuring-cloudinary-with-strapi-3-1-4-6dbddc721617)

However production is broken with the following error while trying to upload to library

```
Error: Internal Server Error
    Cf https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/admin/main.xxxx.chunk.js:1
```

Also in dev when I do the query the image url is still the local one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which worked for me
[Heroku config](https://forum.strapi.io/t/cloudinary-upload-configuration-help/717/5)